# page is not redirecting properly using header in php

Tags: php, redirect

What i am trying to do is redirect the logged in member to index2.php if he try to move back to index.php

I put this piece of code on the very top of index.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    header ("Location :index2.php");
} else {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
}
```

the expected behavior for this code is to redirect the member back to index2.php but it does not and index.php is running , how can i fix that ?

Comment: What happened when you debugged to ensure that `$_SESSION['uid']` actually was set? And did you receive any error messages about "headers already being sent"?

Comment: Maybe set the corresponding session value? How can we know, that it is set somewhere, why and how?

Comment: Use `exit(header(...));` and turn on `error_reporting`.

Comment: Couple things. Try `var_dump($_SESSION)` to make sure it is set, and also change your header argument to `Location: index.php` (noticing the spacing)

Comment: it has to be: header ("Location: index2.php"); the ":" has to go after Location without a space.

Comment: $_SESSION['uid'] is set , i echoed it out and it is set and no error messages about header already sent !

Comment: a) Your spacing between the header name and the value is odd, it should be `name: value` rather than `name :value` b) you should try explicitly setting a HTTP response code (such as 301, 302, 303 etc) c) the specification for the `Location:` header requires a **full** URI, not a relative path (i.e. `http://server/path/to/file` instead of `file` or `/path/to/file`)

Comment: @jprofitt it was the spacing issue , thanks alot :) it is working now perfectly as expected.

Comment: have you tried echoing out your session array to see what is actually being stored? <?php echo print_r($_SESSION);?>

Comment: Accept Kieran's answer then :)

Comment: @DaveRandom how can i set HTTP response code ??

Comment: @wfareed for example `header("HTTP/1.1 302 Found");` or `header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this is because of your space within the code? Try this...

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    header ("Location: index2.php");
} else {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
}
```

Notice the change to `location:`